# Stencil image for texture painting shifted too far away from viewport center

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting

[image]

Hello,

I am facing this issue where the image is not centered to the mouse, hence I can't paint. Do you have any idea how to reset this picture position to put it under mouse cursor while painting?

Answer (score 0):

Hold right mouse button, click on the image to move.